# AWS Cognito - IAM - Deny all access to public/unauth users - Federated

Tags: api, amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-cognito

I have a web app, connecting to backend using cognito, all in aws services. Have a public api method (Lambda) that does the call to cognito to do the auth and give back the session token, etc. all from backend, the problem is that any person can anyway access cognito api from web directly (connecting to aws api directly), I don't want that... how can I define a policy so no public access to cognito is granted to users?

of course users that know my user pool/cognito id

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's probably a few ways to go with this. Here's three ideas that come to mind.

- Cognito federated identities links two roles to your identity pool, one for unauthneticated users and one for authenticated. You could give no permissions to the unauth role and only let people access it once they've signed in with some provider (e.g. Facebook).
- You could put the Lambda behind API Gateway, then secure access to that with federated identities (using the above strategy).
- Finally, you could also authenticate API Gateway using Cognito user pools. API Gateway has a tight integration with user pools, so all you have to do is sign in and provide one of the returned login tokens to authenticate.

Comment: Thanks, I tried to Deny access to all services in the unauth role, but anyway I can call Credentials... method from web sdk... should I change the trust relationship? I tried changing the policy, as I wasn't sure what to change in the trust rel. (also tried deny all actions on the auth role, just to see if that worked, and it didn't)

Comment: The roles Cognito uses define what the credentials you get can do, so they only apply after you've already gotten them. So, they can't stop you from getting them. The only way to do that is remove Cognito from the parts where you don't want someone to be able to get credentials.

Comment: Deny everything just means the credentials they get are useless.